# Last 5 months records dynamically in Oracle without sysdate

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get the total records for last 5 months basis on the latest date in my data-set. 
select max(stock_day) from dwh_fact_stocks; Gives 05-JUL-19

I am using below query to get the desired output but this is not dynamic:
Select count(*) from dwh_fact_stocks where to_char(stock_day,'yyyymm') in ('201906','201905','201904','201903','201902')

Output = 2,8792,016

I want to make the query dynamic and don't want to use sysdate as it is not giving correct result. Please advise.

Comment: max date is `05-JUL-19`. and in your query, you are avoiding July month itself? What is the exact logic?

Comment: As per sysdate, current month would be Aug. That's why I am not considering sysdate because I would include July,Jun, May,Apr,Mar in the result. In my dataset, the latest date is fro July (5-Jul-2019) so it should give me records from Jun,May,Apr, Mar, Feb which is correct.

Comment: Then I must say the only answer provided on this question will not provide you desired result.

Comment: I have prepared the query for you. See my answer.

Comment: Tejash, I got your reply but I don't want to use join as my model is very heavy. Is there any other way that give similar result without using join. Appreciate your response.

Comment: I tried this one and it worked-

Select * from dwh_fact_stocks 
where to_char(stock_day,'yyyymm') 
between (select to_char(Add_months(Max(stock_day),-5),'YYYYMM') from dwh_fact_stocks)
and (select to_char(Add_months(Max(stock_day),-1),'YYYYMM') from dwh_fact_stocks)

Comment: Tejash, I tried your query also and it worked successfully. Thanks a lot for your quick response. You are CHAMP!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following query will work for you.

See the description of code as an inline comment.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    DWH_FACT_STOCKS
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            TRUNC(MAX(STOCK_DAY), 'MONTH') AS MAXDATE  -- IN YOUR CASE 01-JULY-2019
            -- FIRST DAY OF THE MONTH OF THE MAX DATE
        FROM
            DWH_FACT_STOCKS
    ) MAX_DATE ON STOCK_DAY BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(MAXDATE, - 5) AND MAXDATE - 1;
    -- JOIN BASED ON STOCK_DAY BETWEEN
    -- MUST BE GREATER THAN MAXDATE - 5 MONTHS 
    -- IN YOUR CASE MAXDATE - 5 MONTHS  = 01-FEB-2019
    -- AND
    -- MUST BE LESS THAN MAXDATE - 1
    -- IN YOUR CASE MAXDATE - 1 = 06-JUNE-2019
    --
    -- Ultimately condition will be STOCK_DAY between 01-FEB-2019 and 06-JUNE-2019
```

Cheers!!

**-- Update --**

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            D.*,
            TRUNC(MAX(STOCK_DAY) OVER(), 'MONTH') AS MAXDATE  -- IN YOUR CASE 01-JULY-2019
            -- FIRST DAY OF THE MONTH OF THE MAX DATE
        FROM
            DWH_FACT_STOCKS D
    )
WHERE
    STOCK_DAY BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(MAXDATE, - 5) AND MAXDATE - 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Yesssss. This is the one. Thanks Tejash! Really appreciate. Cheers to you!!

Comment: I don't find any issue in this JOIN as the inner query will contain only one row. But still if you want the solution without JOIN then see my answer -- Updated section

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
with t as (select max(stock_day) as maxDate from dwh_fact_stocks)
SELECT *
FROM dwh_fact_stocks
   JOIN t ON stock_day > ADD_MONTHS(maxDate, -5)
```

If you like to get the full month then use `TRUNC(max(stock_day), 'MM') as maxDate`

Comment: I am using your query but Its taking 6 months records including July itself.

with t as (select TRUNC(max(stock_day),'MM') as maxDate from dwh_fact_stocks)
SELECT DISTINCT Stock_day 
FROM dwh_fact_stocks
   JOIN t ON stock_day > ADD_MONTHS(maxDate, -5)

output:
31-MAY-19
30-JUN-19
31-MAR-19
30-APR-19
28-FEB-19
05-JUL-19

I don't want to use july. It should give records from FEB to JUN.